# Indefinite integration of rational functions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

What will be the integral of $\dfrac{x^3+x+1}{x^4+x^2+1}$?
I tried dividing the denominator by the numerator but it didn't work. I also tried partial fractions but I seem to be doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried separating all the terms but it becomes quite lengthy.

Comment: @AshthaLohia You need to be more specific about your difficulties... What went wrong with partial fractions?

Comment: hint: $x^4+x^2+1 = (x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $x^4+x^2+1 = (x^4+2x^2+1) - x^2 = (x^2+1)^2-x^2 = (x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$
So we have the following:
$(x^3+x+1)/(x^4+x^2+1) = ((x+1)(x^2-x+1) + x)/((x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1))$
The rest should be too simple, try it.